# How can I create an object that I can concat onto an array in React?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, javascript-objects

This is the array I would like to concat to

```
venues: [
        {
          name: "Picnic",
          rating: 5
        },
        {
          name: "Mr Tulk",
          rating: 4
        },
        {
          name: "Auction Rooms",
          rating: 3,
        }
      ]
```

This is the code for my class where I am getting the value from the input.
I have set the key to the variable holding the values of the input but am getting a syntax error.

```
class AddVenue extends React.Component {
  onFormSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const venueName = e.target.elements.name.value;
    const rating = e.target.elements.rating.value;
    if (venueName && rating) {
     {
       name: venueName,
       rating: rating
     } 
    }
  }
  render() {

      return (
          <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}>
              <input type="text" name="name" />
              <input type="text" rating="rating" />
              <button>Add Venue</button>
          </form>
      )
   }
}
```

Also I figure I don't need to assign it to a variable or create a new instance as each object in my array isn't assigned to a variable?

I don't want to use a JSON object yet as I want to keep it really basic for now as I'm learning and playing with React and JavaScript

Could you also please explain why this doesn't work and why your answer works please :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
if (venueName && rating) {
 {
   name: venueName,
   rating: rating
 }
```

Change it to

```
if (venueName && rating) {
  venues.push({
    name: venueName,
    rating: rating
  });
}
```

`venues` is an array and hence in order to add new element into it, you can use `push` method